# Matplotlib pie chart - How to center label?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I added rotated labels to my pie chart and expected that by default labels would be centered in each slice of the pie chart. But this is not the case

How can I center my labels?

Here my backend code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget
from frontend import Ui_MainWindow
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.graph = MyCanvas()      
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graph, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.graph.figure.clf()
        self.axes = self.graph.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.y = [1,2,3, 4,8,16,32]
        self.label = ['1.52%', '3.03%', '4.55%', '6.06%', '12.12%', '24.24%', '48.48%']
        self.axes.pie(self.y, labels=self.label, labeldistance=0.6, rotatelabels =True)

class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        self.figure.patch.set_facecolor("None")
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, bottom=0.10, right=0.99, top=0.97)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = Ui_MainWindow()
    prog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean of `center label`?

Comment: I would like that the alignment of labels is centered. For example, the 3.03% is too near to the top edge of the slice.

Comment: if you realize the problem is caused by the size of the label, that is, the text is on the line that divides the middle of the Pie.

Comment: If I understand correctly a slice representing less than 5% will have the label not centered? Because it's seemed that from 5%, labels are correct.

Comment: no, check well, all the labels are not centered, so you understand me draw a line that divides the slice in half, and above that line the text is drawn, that is, the base of the text is in the line that divides Each slice in the middle, in the case that the slice is small, the effect is noted, so the general idea of the solution is to calculate the height of the text, calculate the corresponding angle and rotate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html), you can pass dedicated options to the text objects in your pie chart using the `textprops` keyword. `textprops` accepts a `dict`, which apparently accepts all options that are accepted by [matplotlib.text.Text](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text). Feeding it the options `rotation_mode='anchor'`, `va='center'` and `ha='left'` gives pretty good results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure = plt.figure()
figure.patch.set_facecolor("None")
figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, bottom=0.10, right=0.99, top=0.97)
figure.clf()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
axes.set_aspect(1)
y = [1,2,3, 4,8,16,32]
label = ['1.52%', '3.03%', '4.55%', '6.06%', '12.12%', '24.24%', '48.48%']
axes.pie(
    y, labels=label, labeldistance=0.6, rotatelabels =True,
    textprops = dict(rotation_mode = 'anchor', va='center', ha='left'),
)

plt.show()
```

The result of the code looks like this:

[image: result of above code]

Note that I added `ax.set_aspect(1)` to make the pie chart circular. If you don't want that, just leave out that line.