# Labels alignmnet pie chart / matplotlib 2.1.0+

Tags: matplotlib, label, alignment, pie-chart, labeling

I am having a question regarding a `pie-chart` labels alignment.
I'd like to have labels outside the pie-chart and centered to each wedge. 
According to the documentation page,  "`labeldistance`" parameter  enables to place labels outside the pie-chart, and `"ha" & "va"` parameters supposed to center. However, these two options (ha & va) seems not working on `Matplotlib v2.1.0+`. 
1) With this example (pls see below), you can see that "***car***" label is not centered properly, it is a bit off the center.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
axes.set_aspect(1)  # circular pie
y = [1,2,3, 4,8,16,18]
label = ['car','domino', 'romancical','testing1', 'thisisthelonglabel', 
         'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff', 'as']
wedges, texts = plt.pie(y, 
                        radius=1.2, 
                        labels=label, 
                        labeldistance=1.0, 
                        rotatelabels =True,
                        startangle = 10,
                        wedgeprops = {"linewidth": 0.7, 
                                      "edgecolor": "white"},
                        textprops = dict(ha="center", 
                                          va="center")) # doesn't work 
plt.show()
```

[image]

I added the following lines to force labels to be centered, which works but disabled "`labeldistance`" parameter. So all my centered correctly, as I want labels are overlapping with the pie-chart circle.

```
    wedges, texts = plt.pie(y, 
                            radius=1.2, 
                            labels=label, 
                            labeldistance=1.0, 
                            rotatelabels =True,
                            startangle = 10,
                            wedgeprops = {"linewidth": 0.7, 
                                          "edgecolor": "white"},
                            textprops = dict(ha="center", 
                                              va="center"))
for t in texts:
       t.set_horizontalalignment("center")
       t.set_verticalalignment("center")
 plt.show()
```

[image]

So my question is, do "`ha`" & "`va`" options work for other users?
And could anyone advice if there is a solution for keeping "`labeldistance`" while using `.set_horizontalalignment("center")` and `set_verticalalignment("center")` ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are setting both horizontal and vertical alignments to 'center', but what you want is to only set the vertical alignment to 'center'. In other words, remove the lines `ha="center"` and `t.set_horizontalalignment("center")`. If anything, set the horizontal alignment to 'left'.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52027010/2454357), it may be related.

Comment: For me, on 2.2.2, both your codes generate the second figure

Comment: @ThomasKühn: Hiding `ha` or setting it to left also doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Bazingaa I only have Maplotlib 3.0.2 available.

Comment: @Thomas Kühn: the output remains the same even if I remove set_horizontalalignment & ha options. Thanks for the link , I already went through it thoroughly. It makes me think that this issue is specifically related to Matplotlib v2.1.0

Answer (score 4):

In matplotlib 3.0.2 as well as 2.1.2, using

```
textprops = dict(va="center", rotation_mode = 'anchor')
```

(and `labeldistance=1.05`) results in

[image]

Note that this leaves out the `ha="center"` option, because the horizontal alignment is best be automatically set depending on if the label is on the left or right side of the circle.

For an explanation of `rotation_mode` see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874689/getting-labels-on-top-of-bar-in-polar-radial-bar-chart-in-matplotlib-python3/46876886#46876886) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143395/align-arbitrarily-rotated-text-annotations-relative-to-the-text-not-the-boundin/46892002#46892002).